# Mongoid: search in has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using mongoid, and have the following code:

```
class Users::User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :username, type: String
  has_many :emails, class_name: "Users::Email"
end

class Users::Email
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email, type: String

  belongs_to :user, class_name: "Users::User", inverse_of: :emails
end
```

database:

```
#users collection
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5162de8a359f10cbf700000c"),
  "username" : "bilbo"
}

#emails collection
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5162de8a359f10cbf700000b"),
  "email" : "bilbo@jenkins.com",
  "user_id" : ObjectId("5162de8a359f10cbf700000c"),
}
```

I'm trying to find with the following query:

```
Users::User.includes(:emails).any_of({username: login},{"emails.email"=> login}).first
```

and I don't know why, but this query ignoring search in emails relation.
When `login = "bilbo"` => true, but when `login = "bilbo@jenkins.com"` => nil

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a join to do what you're trying to do and Mongoid doesn't have joins. If you only need to access the emails through a user, you could denormalize them and embed them in `Users::User`.

```
class Users::User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :username, type: String
  embeds_many :emails, class_name: "Users::Email"
end

class Users::Email
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email, type: String

  embedded_in :user, class_name: "Users::User", inverse_of: :emails
end
```

That way, you can query on a user's emails:

```
irb(main):011:0> login = "bilbo@jenkins.com"
=> "bilbo@jenkins.com"
irb(main):012:0> Users::User.any_of({username: login},{"emails.email"=> login}).first
=> #<Users::User _id: 5163ee96e44f7b0301000001, username: "bilbo">
```

If `Users::Email`'s only property is `email` you could go even a step further and omit the model completely and store the string in an array:

```
class Users::User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :username, type: String
  field :emails, type: Array
end
```

Querying gets even easier:

```
Users::User.any_of({username: login},{"emails"=> login}).first
=> #<Users::User _id: 5163ef95e44f7b6254000001, username: "bilbo", emails: ["bilbo@jenkins.com"]>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `Users::User.any_of({username: login},{emails: login}).first` without the double-quotes?